# GRUCells in TensorFlow: TypeError got multiple values for keyword argument 'num_units'

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I have this very simple toy code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 10])

def new_network(x):
    return  tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(x, num_units=100)

pred = new_network(x)
```

and whatever I do, I get the following error

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'num_units'
```

I'm using TensorFlow 1.3.0 version.

Is that having something to do with [this pulled issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/issues/530)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/GRUCell#__init__) is initialized with `num_units` and activation etc, but not with inputs. Inputs are passed when you use the `__call__` method

```
GRUCell.__init__(
    num_units,
    activation=None,
    reuse=None,
    kernel_initializer=None,
    bias_initializer=None
)

state = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, state_size])
def new_network(x):
    gru_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units=100)
    y = gru_cell(x, state)
pred = new_network(x)
```

Comment: Ah silly me, I get lost in the doc and versioning of TF sometimes. Thanks!